# Quando dou um post no form pego esse erro: TypeError: _co.postCreateTypeFields is not a function

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-6

Esse é meu html:

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="postCreateTypeFields()" style="width:400px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <h1>Types Fields</h1>

    <div class="required-field-block">
        <input formControlName="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome" class="form-control">
        <div class="required-icon">
            <div class="text">*</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="required-field-block">
        <input formControlName="version" type="text" placeholder="Versão" class="form-control">
        <div class="required-icon">
            <div class="text">*</div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Criar</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Componente

```
import { Component, OnInit, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { CreateTypeFieldsService } from '../create-type-fields.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-type-fields',
  templateUrl: './create-type-fields.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-type-fields.component.css'],
  providers: []
})
export class CreateTypeFieldsComponent implements OnInit {

  private _createTypesFields: Model.CreateTypesFields;
  private form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _createTypeService: CreateTypeFieldsService, private builder: FormBuilder) { 

     this.form = this.builder.group({
      name: '',
      version: ''
    })   
  } 
  ngOnInit() {
      this._createTypeService.postCreateTypeFields(this._createTypesFields)
      .subscribe( success => {
        if(success.Result){
          //anything here
        }
      },
      error =>{
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Configuration } from './app.constants';
import {RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CreateTypeFieldsService {

  private actionUrl: string;
  private url: 'http://localhost:56758/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _configuration: Configuration) { 
    this.actionUrl = _configuration.ServerWithApiUrl + 'TypesFields/';
  }

    public postCreateTypeFields(itemName: Model.CreateTypesFields): Observable<any> {
      const toAdd = JSON.stringify({ ItemName: itemName });

      return this.http.post(this.actionUrl, toAdd, httpOptions);
        /
  }
}
```

quando tento consumir a API, dá esse erro

> TypeError: _co.postCreateTypeFields is not a function

Como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função existe no contexto da `CreateTypeFieldsService`, não na classe `CreateTypeFieldsComponent`.

Uma forma de chamar diretamente seria: `_createTypeService.postCreateTypeFields`.

Mas acho que ficaria melhor você criar uma função na classe do componente chamando a função da classe de serviço, algo que você parece estar fazendo dentro da `OnInit`.

```
onPostCreateTypeFields(values: any) {
  this._createTypeService.postCreateTypeFields(this._createTypesFields)
      .subscribe( success => {
        if(success.Result){
          //anything here
        }
      },
      error =>{
      }
    );
}
```

Para chamar a função você pode usar o botão ao invés do ngsubmit no form, ficando as duas linhas alteradas assim:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" style="width:400px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

O botão:

```
<button (click)="onPostCreateTypeFields(form.values)" class="btn btn-primary" >Criar</button>
```

Comment: Celso, no meu ngOnInit do Component eu tenho isso: `ngOnInit() {
      this._createTypeService.postCreateTypeFields(this._createTypesFields)
      .subscribe( success => {
        if(success.Result){
          //anything here
        }
      }` Onde eu colocaria essa classe? No mesmo component? No ngOnInit, alterando para o exemplo acima?

Comment: Da forma que sugeri, na função deve resolver. Eu não entendi muito bem qual o objetivo daquele trecho de código. Mas observe que o código dentro da `ngOnInit` será chamado após o carregamento do componente, apenas uma vez. Quando movemos para a função ele é chamado a cada clique no mesmo.

Comment: Olá, realmente estava tudo errado. Segui sua orientação, removi o código dentro do Init e resolveu. Agora gera o GUID do mongodb, mas não grava o campo Name, vindo do textbox, mas isso é outro post. Vou encerrar e marcar sua resposta.